# Which dependency does ExceptionMapper for Dropwizard require?

Tags: exception, dropwizard, maven-central

The dropwizard manual suggests to [implement a javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/core.html#error-handling) in order to have more control of the generated responses for error cases. However, it does not tell me which maven dependency to use. The central maven repository yields [dozens of result pages](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3Ajavax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper) for this class. So which artifact should I choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ExceptionMapper` interface should already be pulled in when you reference `dropwizard-core`. You shouldn't need to add any other dependencies.

[`dropwizard-core`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cio.dropwizard%7Cdropwizard-core%7C0.8.0%7Cjar) depends on [`dropwizard-jersey`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cio.dropwizard%7Cdropwizard-jersey%7C0.8.0%7Cjar) which depends on [`jersey-server`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.glassfish.jersey.core%7Cjersey-server%7C2.17%7Cjar) which depends on [`jersey-common`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.glassfish.jersey.core%7Cjersey-common%7C2.17%7Cjar) which depends on [`javax.ws.rs-api`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax.ws.rs%7Cjavax.ws.rs-api%7C2.0.1%7Cjar) which has the `ExceptionMapper` interface.